# Another social network matrix expression assistance please.

Tags: matrices, graph-theory

We consider a collection of n people who participate in a social network in which pairs of people can be connected, by 'friending' each other. The n x n matrix F is the friend matrix, defined by $F_{ij} = 1$ if persons i and j are friends, and $F_{ij} = 0$ if not. We assume that the friend relationship is symmetric, i.e., person i and person ja are friends means person j and person i are  friends. We will also assume that $F_{ii} =0$

C is the nxn matrix with $C_{ij}$ equal to the number of friends persons i and j have in common. (Person k is a friend in common of persons i and j if she is a friend of both person i and person j. The diagonal entry $C_{ii}$, which is the total number of friends person i has in common with herself, is the total number of friends of person i.) Give an expression for C in terms of the matrix F. Briefly justify your expression

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that $k$ is a common friend of $i$ and $j$ iff $F_{i,k}=F_{j,k}=1$, equivalently $F_{i,k}F_{j,k}=1$.  So the number of common friends of $i$ and $j$ is
$$C_{i,j}=\sum_{k=1}^n F_{i,k}F_{j,k}=\sum_{k=1}^n F_{i,k}F_{k,j}.$$
Now what matrix operation does that look like?